# Why can't I select perks other than increasing SPECIAL skills at level up?

Tags: fallout-4

I've now hit level four but the only perks available to me are still stat increases.  All the perks at L01 and below are greyed out, and unselectable, even if I meet the pre-requistes.  Is this expected behaviour?  Is there something else I need to do to get other perks?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The perks screen uses fading to indicate a skill you don't have, and outlining to indicate a skill you can't have (due to not meeting the requirements), see this screenshot here:

[image: perks screen]

If you've got skills that are faded out, you should be able to get these by clicking on them and then pressing the confirmation key as prompted at the bottom of the screen:

[image: confirm selection]

If the perk is outlined entirely, hovering over the perk will still tell you what it does but also inform you of why it's outlined (not enough strength in my case).

Comment: Good answer. There's one exception to these general rules: if you already have one or more levels of a skill, that icon looks the same whether or not you meet the requirements for the next level of that skill (these are usually character level requirements). Once you have at least one level in a skill there's no way to differentiate from the icon whether you can or can't upgrade it. So unfortunately you need to hover over every one of these skills to see whether you can upgrade it. Unless I'm missing something--which surely I hope I am.

Comment: @FeralChimp If you already have a point in a perk, you can tell if you can put another point into it by looking at the stars above it. If you have level 2 in a perk and there's only 2 stars there, none flashing, you can't put in another point yet. If there's the 2 stars indicating your current level and a 3rd flashing star, you can put another point into it.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill +1 Nice, I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: OMG. I thought I had to do ALL the first row. Im at level 43 and havent even used anything below the first row! I guess I have a strong base to work with, but geez, what a terribly designed system to not explain this to users. Thanks for the great info.